# ASP email script breaks from error above it

Tags: asp-classic

The email body below (messagebody) was being sent out as blank recently. I found that programmeremail was being queried rather than emailprogrammer above the messagebody. Could that potentially be causing the messagebody to show up as blank? If not, is there anything else that could cause this?

```
''FINDS OUT WHO THE EMAIL IS TO.
            newStepTemp = newStep
            strSQL = " Select Description, orderid,emailMgmt, emailSE,emailSupport,programmeremail FROM RelDoc2 where stepid=" & newStepTemp
            set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)
    addresses=""
    if(rs.fields("emailMgmt")) then
        addresses=addresses
    end if
    if(rs.fields("emailSE")) then
        addresses=addresses & ";" & adminemail
    end if
    if(rs.fields("emailSupport")) then
        addresses=addresses & ";" & setupemail
    end if
    if(rs.fields("emailProgrammer")) then
        addresses=addresses & ";" & programmeremail
    end if

    ''WHAT DOES THE MESSAGE SAY?
    messagebody = "<style type='text/css'>table.styled{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13;}" &_
    "<table class='styled'>" &_
    "<tr><td><b>Relationship</b>: <a href='https://example.com/details.asp?relno="&relno&"'>" & aname & "-" & bname & "</a></td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td><b>Document</b>: " & document & "</td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td><b>New Status</b>: " & rs.fields("Description") & "</td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td><b><u>Other Details</u></b></td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td><b>Communication Method</b>: " & protocol & "</td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td><b>Int Type</b>: " & intType & "</td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td><b>Misc.</b>: " & additionalDetails & "</td></tr>" &_
    "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" &_
    "</table>"


    ''EMAIL THE MESSAGE
    Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    myMail.Subject= "Update for " & aname & "-" & bname & " – " & document
    myMail.From=empemail
    myMail.To= addresses  
    myMail.HTMLBody= messagebody
```

Comment: If the body is empty then you need to check if any of parameters that build it are "nothing" (document, rs.,fields("description") etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
''WHAT DOES THE MESSAGE SAY?
messagebody = "<html><head> <style type='text/css'>table.styled{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13;} </style></head>" &_
"<body> <table class='styled'>" &_
"<tr><td><b>Relationship</b>: <a href='https://example.com/details.asp?relno="&relno&"'>" & aname & "-" & bname & "</a></td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td><b>Document</b>: " & document & "</td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td><b>New Status</b>: " & rs.fields("Description") & "</td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td><b><u>Other Details</u></b></td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td><b>Communication Method</b>: " & protocol & "</td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td><b>Int Type</b>: " & intType & "</td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td><b>Misc.</b>: " & additionalDetails & "</td></tr>" &_
"<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>" &_
"</table> </body></html>"
```

I hope help you!